# Stack Overflow-like JavaScript warning and w3c HTML validation

Tags: css, w3c-validation, noscript

I have a website that relies heavily on JavaScript. While most of the stuff downgrades nicely, the functionally is really second-grade. So, I wish to alert the users that they should turn JS on if they have disabled it. To do this, I use NOSCRIPT to show a div with alert a top of the page, similar to how Stack Overflow does it.

This div covers top of the page content, so I have to move the document body down. Since JS is not available one has to use CSS, and I use something like: `margin-top: 8px`. The complete HTML looks like this:

```
<noscript>
<style type="text/css">body { margin-top:8em; }</style>
<div class="warn">WARNING<br>Turn on JavaScript for best experience</div>
</noscript>
```

The problem is: where do I place this code?

I tried in the HEAD section, in the BODY section, after the BODY, but wherever it is placed, W3C HTML markup validator complains that either *document type does not allow element "STYLE" here* or *document type does not allow element "BODY" here*

I even tried to separate CSS and DIV into two parts and find a proper placement for each of them, but got the same errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may just have to suck it up and accept your page will not validate.

*...or* change how it works. Can you place it first with `position: static` so it naturally pushes your page content down?

*...or*, to be tricky make your `body` always have `margin-top: 8em`. Then on DOM ready (or window load) in JavaScript, make it 0.

#### CSS

```
body {
   margin-top: 8em;
}

body.javascript {
   margin-top: 0;
}
```

#### JavaScript

```
window.onload = function() {
   document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].className += ' javascript';
};
```

Comment: Won't that cause the margin to be visible while the page is loading?

Comment: @Alexandre Jasmin Yeah, just look at cross browser DOM ready event. Or use `$(function() { });` or equivalent in a JavaScript library.

Answer (score -1):

You need to have a block element (e.g. div) inside the noscript element AND move the style element inside the head element to gain proper validation.

Comment: You're missing the point. Style needs to be applied only when JavaScript is not available. Therefore it has to be inside NOSCRIPT tag.